# RuntimeError when running sklearn.model_selection.cross_validation in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run the `cross_validation` method over a set of data using a `LearningShapelet` as the estimator in a **Jupyter Notebook environment**.

```
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

from tslearn.shapelets import LearningShapelets

shp_clf = LearningShapelets(n_shapelets_per_size={5:1},
                            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(.01),
                            #batch_size=16,
                            weight_regularizer=.01,
                            max_iter=1000,
                            random_state=42,
                            verbose=0)

scores = cross_validate(shp_clf, pattern_2, values_2, cv=5, scoring = ['precision', 'recall', 'accuracy'])
```

However I'm receiving error with this call stack:

```
Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:862, in Parallel.dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    861 try:
--> 862     tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
    863 except queue.Empty:
    864     # slice the iterator n_jobs * batchsize items at a time. If the
    865     # slice returns less than that, then the current batchsize puts
   (...)
    868     # accordingly to distribute evenly the last items between all
    869     # workers.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:266, in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    263 # We clone the estimator to make sure that all the folds are
    264 # independent, and that it is pickle-able.
    265 parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose, pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
--> 266 results = parallel(
    267     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    268         clone(estimator),
    269         X,
    270         y,
    271         scorers,
    272         train,
    273         test,
    274         verbose,
    275         None,
    276         fit_params,
    277         return_train_score=return_train_score,
    278         return_times=True,
    279         return_estimator=return_estimator,
    280         error_score=error_score,
    281     )
    282     for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups)
    283 )
    285 _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(results, error_score)
    287 # For callabe scoring, the return type is only know after calling. If the
    288 # return type is a dictionary, the error scores can now be inserted with
    289 # the correct key.
...Really long chain of calls into sklearn modules
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py:63, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
     58 config = get_config()
     59 iterable_with_config = (
     60     (_with_config(delayed_func, config), args, kwargs)
     61     for delayed_func, args, kwargs in iterable
     62 )
---> 63 return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3598, in _DefaultDistributionStrategy.__deepcopy__(***failed resolving arguments***)
   3596 def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
   3597   del memo
-> 3598   raise RuntimeError("Should only create a single instance of "
   3599                      "_DefaultDistributionStrategy")

RuntimeError: Should only create a single instance of _DefaultDistributionStrategy
```

According to ChatGPT, this problem is caused because the interpreter is trying to distribute the execution of the code and failing to do so. I tried to change the parallelization strategy, and changing the `n_jobs` parametre, with no success. The notebook was prepared to run with `tensorflow@1.15` but since `pip install Tensorflow==1.15` returned an error I just installed last version. In line with this, ChatGPT suggested using

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
```

Which only helped to change the error messages with no real progress.